# Trouble structuring v-if as a filter inside a v-for using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having a bit of trouble setting up a `v-if` with a `v-for`, since I am very new to Vue. I currently have:

```
<div class="row form-group" v-for="(article, key, index) in articles" :key="key" v-if="article.pubdate(first four characters)">={{ filterYear}} >
```

I'm not sure how to get the first four characters of the `pubdate` to be treated as a number, and also how to pass in the `filterYear`.
`articles` is a JSON object that is returned using Axios. However, `pubdate` is formatted as: year, space, then month. For example:

```
2007 Aug
/* or */
2009 Aug 1
```

What I need to do is to identify a year, and pass it into the `v-if`, so only articles written during or after the year will show up. I have similar code on the JavaScript side that identifies values and puts them into a string ( `uid_string`). See [Codepen](https://codepen.io/morgenweck/pen/LoZLqZ?editors=1111).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `v-if` loop filter, I recommend a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) to simplify the loop's template a bit. Another advantage to this solution over the other is it removes the need for additional ordinal number calculation of each item, since the ordinal naturally matches the item's array index incremented by 1.

For example, you could move the filter suggested by @Stephen into a computed property:

```html
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    filteredArticles() {
      const { articles, filterYear } = this
      return Object.values(articles)
        .filter(article => parseInt(article.pubdate.substring(0,4)) >= filterYear)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then, use the computed property in your template like this:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="(article, index) in filteredArticles" :key="article.uid">
   ...
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vwKJQa?editors=1010)

Comment: Fantastic-- Thank you to the both of you.

Comment: @user1314159 No problem :)

Answer (score 2):

To get an integer year from first four characters:

```js
parseInt(article.pubdate.substring(0, 4))
```

```
<div  
v-for="(article, key, index) in articles" 
:key="key" 
v-if="parseInt(article.pubdate.substring(0, 4))>=filterYear">

Your code here... 
To print the article JSON put it in braces: {{article}}.
Or the date {{article.date}}, etc.
Don't put the braces in your template attribute value though.

</div>
```

The beauty of `Vue` is that all template properties are relative to the component, so you do not need to use `this.` to reference them.

You can also clean up the template by moving the parseInt(...) and comparison to a component method.

Here is your codepen with these changes:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVrvre?editors=1111

Comment: Fantastic-- Thank you

Comment: In the codepen example how can I change the line number to be sequential? The code is written to show the index but since every row is not shown the numbers skip  In normal JavaScript I would add a  i +=1 in the loop but that's not possible in Vue

Comment: @user1314159 If you also need to display a different index, you'd be better off using a computed property to pre-filter the array by year. Then you could remove the `v-if` loop filter, simplifying your template.

Comment: create a computed property that returns `articles.filter(...).sort(...)`.  The computed will update when the filter changes. @tony19 offers such an approach.